# Horizontal scrolling boxes with text inside

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am making event listings using a horizontal scrolling box that will have even information listed in each box. How can I make it so that there isn't so much space between the text and the scroll bar?

```css
.scrollbox {
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
  width:750px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  background: white;
    align-content: center;
}

.elem {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:10px;
font-family: montserrat;
}
```

```html
  <div class="scrollbox">
  <div class="elem"><p>What:</p><p>When:</p><p>Where:</p><p>Admission:</p>
        </div>
  <div class="elem"><p>What:</p><p>When:</p><p>Where:</p><p>Admission:</p></div>
  <div class="elem"><p>What:</p><p>When:</p><p>Where:</p><p>Admission:</p></div>
  <div class="elem"><p>What:</p><p>When:</p><p>Where:</p><p>Admission:</p></div>
  <div class="elem">X</div>
  <div class="elem">X</div>
  <div class="elem">X</div>
  <div class="elem">X</div>
  <div class="elem">X</div>
  <div class="elem">X</div>
  <div class="elem">X</div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried dropping the margin on the .elem class? 10px goes all the way around so if you want to have less space on the right try `margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be with `vertical-align`. Try doing:

```css
.elem {
    /* ... */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I don't know in what you'll be using this, so I can't tell whether that's precisely what will work for you. If it ends up breaking something, try setting `vertical-align` to `text-bottom` / `text-top` / `bottom` / `top`, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a bunch.